# multiindex columns sum in pivot pandas

Tags: python, pandas

how to get sum of two columns in multindex pivot table

```
pivot_bad_pod_theft_df=pd.pivot_table(bad_pod_theft_df,index=['DELIVERY_DEPOT'],columns=['Month1','BAD_OPEN_OR_CLOSE_STATUS'],values=['CON_NUMBER'],aggfunc={'CON_NUMBER':len},margins=True,fill_value='')
```

pivot_bad_pod_theft_df.head()

but i want like below sum of open and close in SUM column separate.pls guide me.

```
Dec-17      Dec-17 Total
OPEN    CLOSE   
3   3
4   8   12
12  12
3   21  24
1   9   10
3   4   7
1   10  11

27  67  64
```

but i am getting like this

```
Dec-17      Dec-17 
OPEN    CLOSE   
         3  
   4    8   

   3    21  
   1    9   
   3    4   
   1    10
```

i want sum of open and close in SUM column separate

Comment: Can you add sample of `bad_pod_theft_df` ?

Comment: Can you format your data more clearly? Provide some data that we can immediately use by `to_dict()` function "add" expected output more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need:

```
#sum by first level of MultiIndex
df1 = bad_pod_theft_df.sum(axis=1, level=0)
#create MultiIndex
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.columns, ['SUM']])
print (df1)
  Dec-17
     SUM
0      6
1     12
2     33
3     10
4      7
5     11

#join together
df2 = pd.concat([bad_pod_theft_df, df1], axis=1)
print(df2)
  Dec-17          
    OPEN CLOSE SUM
0      3     3   6
1      4     8  12
2     12    21  33
3      1     9  10
4      3     4   7
5      1    10  11
```

Comment: Hmmm, if remove `fill_value` parameter, how does it work? - `pivot_bad_pod_theft_df=pd.pivot_table(bad_pod_theft_df,index=['DELIVERY_DEPOT'],columns=['Month1','BAD_OPEN_OR_CLOSE_STATUS'],values=['CON_NUMBER'],aggfunc={'CON_NUMBER':len})`